# Raspberry Pi 3 losing Wi-Fi connection frequently

Tags: pi-3, wifi

My Raspberry Pi 3 built-in Wi-Fi card has some serious problem. The Wi-Fi connection is lost very frequently (every 5-10 mins). I googled this problem and found some solutions to solve this:

- Turn off the power management of wlan card.

  ```
  sudo iw dev wlan0 set power_save off
  ```
- Keep running this script using crontab

  ```
  /bin/ping -c2 -I $wlan $pingip >/dev/null 2>&1

  if [ $? -ge 1 ] ; then
      echo "Network connection down! Attempting reconnection."
      /sbin/ifdown $wlan  
      /bin/sleep 5
      /sbin/ifup --force $wlan 
  else
      echo "Network is Okay"
  fi
  ```

  I schedule the above script after every 10 min, but still losing connection. Wi-Fi works fine on smartphone and laptop.

What could be the possible reason and its solution?

Comment: power supply ...

Comment: @ppumkin; I don't think so. Its 5V, 2.5 amp power adapter.

Comment: Where did you get it from? Also the USB cable is also very important, where did you get the cable from?

Comment: @ppumkin; https://www.amazon.com/CanaKit-Raspberry-Supply-Adapter-Charger/dp/B00MARDJZ4

Comment: @ppumkin; Already did that. Same problem with charger. I thing something wrong with pi-3 wlan card, though not sure.

Comment: Yea I just saw that charger has allot of good reviews so ill have to back down on that - It works for allot of people so yea. Possibly some other issue :( Try another Pi, aye. Sorry, usually WiFi if power related.

Comment: If you fix it please come back and answer this question

Comment: @ppumkin; Sure.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem (RPi's Wi-Fi had been working about 5 minutes after boot). And fixed it by switching Wi-Fi channel from 12th to 3rd on my HUAWEI router. (In North America 12,13,14 channels is low power [Wikipedia WLAN channels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels#Interference_concerns))